# Linux libudev test application not receiving REMOVE events

Tags: c, linux, usb, udev

I am creating a test application for a new platform that we are working on to test `libudev` and make sure our `C` application will be able to be properly notified when a particular `usb` device is inserted or removed.

On our system every time this device is removed and added it's mounted in a different location such as `/dev/hidraw0` or `/dev/hidraw1` etc. So my test application uses `libudev` to both monitor events and enumerate through the `hidraw` devices so it can find where it's been mounted. Every time the device status changes, insertion or removal, the code finds where it's mounted and restarts `libudev` event monitoring.

My questions:

1- I see the "add" events. But why do I never see the remove events?
2- Am I properly closing and restarting the `libudev` monitoring such that resources aren't being leaked?

Sample output:

> Found UGA. SysPath=[/sys/class/hidraw/hidraw2]
>   DevPath=[/dev/hidraw2]
>  Starting monitor returned 2
>
> UGA added....
>  Found UGA. SysPath=[/sys/class/hidraw/hidraw2]
>   DevPath=[/dev/hidraw2]
>  Starting monitor returned 2
>
> UGA added....
>  Found UGA. SysPath=[/sys/class/hidraw/hidraw1] Dev
>   Path=[/dev/hidraw1]
>  Starting monitor returned 2

**EDIT:

What I've seen is that this test application is receiving the `remove` events when run on our much older x86 platform with a 2.6 kernel while the same code running on our new ARM platform with a 3.10.66 kernel doesn't receive the `remove` event.


Could this be a `udev`/`libudev` system configuration or kernel issue?**

Also when running `udevadm monitor` on the ARM board the required `remove` events are being sent as shown below. So why isn't `libudev` not forwarding them to my application?

```
box:/home/eng$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[80296.266707] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001D (hid)
KERNEL[80296.266864] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [80296.267553] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001D (hid)
KERNEL[80296.267695] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [80296.268031] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [80296.268890] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[80304.423516] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[80304.424514] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[80304.427211] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E (hid)
KERNEL[80304.458031] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [80304.460096] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [80304.467105] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [80304.472885] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E (hid)
UDEV  [80304.474903] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
```

Test Code:

```
/* Linux */
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/hidraw.h>
#include <linux/fd.h>

/* Unix */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libudev.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/* C */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#endif


struct udev *udev;
struct udev_monitor *udevMonitor;
int mon_fd = -1;
int fd = -1;
char sysPath[50];
char devPath[50];


enum { DEVICE_NO_CHANGE = 0, DEVICE_ADD, DEVICE_REMOVE, DEVICE_MOVED };
enum { OFFLINE = 0, ONLINE };
enum { ENABLED = 1, DISABLED };
enum { FAILED = 0, PENDING , ACTIVE };


void msSleep(int milliseconds);
void GetUGAMountPoints(void);
int StartUDEVMonitor(void);
int usb_check_device_status(void);

void GetUGAMountPoints(void)
{
    struct udev_device *dev;
    struct udev_enumerate *enumerate;
    struct udev_list_entry *devices, *dev_list_entry;

    strcpy( devPath, "/dev/hidraw" );

    /* Create a list of the devices in the 'hidraw' subsystem. */
    enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(udev);
    udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "hidraw");
    udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enumerate);
    devices = udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate);

    udev_list_entry_foreach(dev_list_entry, devices)
    {
        const char *path;

        path = udev_list_entry_get_name(dev_list_entry);
        dev = udev_device_new_from_syspath(udev, path);
        dev = udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype( dev, "usb", "usb_device");
        if (!dev)
        {
            printf("Unable to find parent usb device.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if( !strcmp(udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idVendor"), "0a70") &&
                !strcmp(udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idProduct"), "0441") )
            {
                char num = path[ strlen(path) - 1 ];
                devPath[ strlen(devPath) ] = num;

                /* Yes I know this sprintf() is insecure and lazy
                   This code is just for testing and not going into
                   production in this form
                */
                sprintf(sysPath, "/sys/class/hidraw/hidraw%c", num);

                printf("Found UGA. SysPath=[%s] Dev Path=[%s]\n", sysPath, devPath);
                udev_device_unref(dev);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                udev_device_unref(dev);
            }
        }
    }

    udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
    return;
}


int StartUDEVMonitor(void)
{
    int retCode = ACTIVE;

    /* Create the udev object */
    udev = udev_new();
    if (!udev)
    {
        retCode = FAILED;
    }
    else
    {
        GetUGAMountPoints();

        /* Set up a monitor to monitor hidraw devices */
        udevMonitor = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink(udev, "kernel");
        udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(udevMonitor, "hidraw", NULL);
        udev_monitor_enable_receiving(udevMonitor);

        mon_fd = udev_monitor_get_fd(udevMonitor);
        fd = open(devPath, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);

        if (fd < 0)
        {
            retCode = PENDING;
        }
    }
    return( retCode );
}

int usb_check_device_status(void)
{
    struct udev_device *dev;
    char action[25];  
    int retCode = DEVICE_NO_CHANGE;

    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int ret;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(mon_fd, &fds);
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 75000;

    do
    {
        ret = select(mon_fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        /* Check if our file descriptor has received data. */
        if (ret > 0 && FD_ISSET(mon_fd, &fds))
        {
            FD_CLR(mon_fd, &fds);
            /* Make the call to receive the device.
               select() ensured that this will not block. */
            dev = udev_monitor_receive_device(udevMonitor);
            if (dev)
            {
                strcpy( action, udev_device_get_action(dev));
                printf("usb_check_device_status()::[%s]\n", action);

                if( !strcmp("remove",action))
                {
                    printf("UGA removed....\n");
                    retCode = DEVICE_REMOVE;
                }
                else if( !strcmp("add",action))
                {
                    printf("UGA added....\n");
                    retCode = DEVICE_ADD;
                }
                else if( !strcmp("move",action))
                {
                    printf("UGA moved....\n");
                    retCode = DEVICE_MOVED;
                }
                udev_device_unref(dev);
            }
        }
    }while( ret != 0 );
    return( retCode );
}


void msSleep(int milliseconds)
{
      usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int status = StartUDEVMonitor();
    printf("Starting monitor returned %d\n",status);

    if(status == ACTIVE )
    {
        while(1)
        {
            if( usb_check_device_status() != DEVICE_NO_CHANGE )
            {
                close(fd);
                close(mon_fd);
                udev_monitor_unref(udevMonitor);
                udev_unref(udev);
                StartUDEVMonitor();
                printf("Starting monitor returned %d\n\n",status);
            }
            msSleep(75);
        }
    }
    return( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by looking at the output of `udevadm monitor` I was able to see that on the newer kernel on the ARM board the `remove` events aren't `tagged` with hidraw as they are with the `add` event as shown below:

```
box:/home/eng$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[80296.266707] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001D (hid)
KERNEL[80296.266864] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [80296.267553] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001D (hid)
KERNEL[80296.267695] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [80296.268031] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [80296.268890] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[80304.423516] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[80304.424514] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[80304.427211] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E (hid)
KERNEL[80304.458031] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [80304.460096] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [80304.467105] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [80304.472885] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E (hid)
UDEV  [80304.474903] add      /devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A70:0441.001E/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
```

So by changing the filter setup in `StartUDEVMonitor()` from:

```
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(udevMonitor, "hidraw", NULL);
```

to:

```
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(udevMonitor, "hid", NULL);
```

the application now reliably receives both `remove` and `add` events on the newer platform with the newer kernel.